# catkin_make error : 'float32' does not name a type

Tags: ros, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, when i do the catkin_make command I get the following error :

```
[ 93%] Built target mastering_ros_demo_pkg_generate_messages
[ 93%] Built target irobot_generate_messages
[ 94%] Building CXX object irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp.o
[ 96%] Built target add_two_ints_client
[ 98%] Built target add_two_ints_server
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:6:1: error: ‘float32’ does not name a type
 float32 data[3];
 ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp: In function ‘void u1Callback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:10:3: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
   data[0]=r1->range;
   ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp: In function ‘void u2Callback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:15:3: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
   data[1]=r1->range;
   ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:15:11: error: ‘r1’ was not declared in this scope
   data[1]=r1->range;
           ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp: In function ‘void u3Callback(const ConstPtr&)’:
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:20:3: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
   data[2]=r1->range;
   ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:20:11: error: ‘r1’ was not declared in this scope
   data[2]=r1->range;
           ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:40:2: error: ‘msg’ was not declared in this scope
  msg.rages[i]  = data[i];
  ^
/home/osaka/catkin_ws/src/irobot/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp:40:18: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
  msg.rages[i]  = data[i];
                  ^
irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/src/range_to_laserscan.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4362: recipe for target 'irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [irobot/CMakeFiles/range_to_laserscan.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

roscpp code :

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/Range.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h"
#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"

float32 data[3];

void u1Callback(const sensor_msgs::Range::ConstPtr& r1)
{
  data[0]=r1->range;
}

void u2Callback(const sensor_msgs::Range::ConstPtr& r2)
{
  data[1]=r1->range;
}

void u3Callback(const sensor_msgs::Range::ConstPtr& r3)
{
  data[2]=r1->range;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
   ros::init(argc, argv, "rang_to_laserscan");
   ros::NodeHandle n;

   ros::Subscriber sub_u1 = n.subscribe("/ultrasound1", 1000, u1Callback);
   ros::Subscriber sub_u2 = n.subscribe("/ultrasound2", 1000, u2Callback);
   ros::Subscriber sub_u3 = n.subscribe("/ultrasound3", 1000, u3Callback);

   ros::Publisher pub1 = n.advertise<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("/pub1", 100);

   ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

   while (ros::ok())
   {
      sensor_msgs::LaserScan msg1;
      
      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
           msg.rages[i]  = data[i];
      }   

      pub1.publish(msg1);

      ros::spinOnce();

      loop_rate.sleep();
   }

   return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/265245/catkin_make-error-:-%27float32%27-does-not-name-a-type/) by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-06-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) on 2017-06-30**:
Check out here: http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since you have included `#include "std_msgs/Float32.h"`, you should use `std_msgs::Float32 data[3]` instead of `float32 data[3]`

---

Originally posted by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) with karma: 272 on 2017-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [أسامة الادريسي](https://answers.ros.org/users/30880/%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%B3%D9%8A/) on 2017-06-30**:
thank you, it work